# How to be sure a Motherboard supports Intel Active Management Technology (AMT)

Tags: linux, intel, amt, out-of-band-management

I'm looking to build a light-weight rack-mounted Linux system, and I would love to be able to include some sort of remote management.  At the very least, remote power on/off, and a little bit of fault investigation.

Can anybody confirm my understanding.  In order to support AMT, I need:

(a) An vPro-capable Intel CPU.

AND

(c) A vPro-capable Intel M/B.

Is that the correct, necessary-and-sufficient list?

For a list of what is "vPro-capable", it appears that I can use http://ark.intel.com/ and see that basically ALL the 4th-Generation i5 and i7 Intel CPUs support vPro (and hence AMT).

However, motherboards seems a bit more hit-and-miss.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_AMT_versions, Intel AMT 9.0 is supported on Intel 8 Series chipsets.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#5.2F6.2F7.2F8_Series_chipsets the 8-series chipsets are Z87, H87, H81, Q87, Q85 and B85.

According to http://ark.intel.com/ the "Advanced Technologies" list says that the DQ87PG supports vPro, while the DZ87KLT-75K, DB85FL, DH87RL and DH87MC do NOT.

That's a pretty bad hit rate... only 1 out of 5!

So what's going on here?  Did I misunderstand something along the line, or is Intel basically not supporting AMT on its latest chipset series boards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the Q87 chipset supports the vPro feature. This is nothing new, it was always only the Qxy chipsets that supported all remote management and server features.
See here for a comparison of all latest Intel chipsets: http://ark.intel.com/compare/75010,75013,75007,75004,75019